# pgbouncer: FATAL cannot load config file

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I'm trying to start pgbouncer on a Windows server but I'm getting the error:

```
FATAL cannot load config file
```

I downloaded the install from:
https://winpg.jp/~saito/pgbouncer/

I have registered the DLL.

My config file, as per the instructions is:

```
[databases]
template1 = host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=template1

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 6543
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
auth_type = md5
auth_file = users.txt
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
admin_users = postgres
```

And my users.txt is:

```
"postgres" "md52789c829ed005483db36bec2438f82674"
```

Is there any way to see what the problem is?
The error message is not very helpful :)

Thanks.

Comment: there can be some strange white char maybe

Comment: @PavelStehule, I just checked. No extra chars.

Comment: maybe access rights? Windows are strange sometimes

Comment: Are you using win32 or 64? may be the app is 64 and you have the 32 bit version or vice versa.

Comment: I've tried with both

Comment: You can get a more verbose output to help debug the issue with your config file by passing the -v [argument](https://pgbouncer.github.io/usage.html#command-line-switches) when starting pgbouncer. Lines in the config file that are successfully parsed will show "ok:1", while any line(s) that is causing issues will show "ok:0".

Comment: What I found was that the end of the pgbouncer.ini there is a line 
%include /var/opt/gitlab/consul/databases.ini and there was no such file present on my system and hence i was getting the problem. 
Remember mine is a linux system so the path names might change for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your current terminal user has the right execution permission for your pgbouncer.ini file.